# form_set_value() does not work during validation for webform

Tags: drupal-7, validation, form-api

I have a webform, and a custom validation function. Which both work fine.

But when I do a form_set_value inside the validation function, nothing happens.

Can anyone help me out please

```
function test_webservices_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {

    if (form_get_errors())
        return;
    $form_values = $form_state['values']['submitted'];

    $Address = _test_webservices_translate($values);
    if (!$Address->succes) {
            form_set_value($form['submitted']['voornaam'], 'sdfdsfsd', $form_state);
            dpm($form);
            dpm($form_state);
    } else {
        _test_webservices_handledcm($form, $form_state, $Address);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nealv: did you ever find a solution here? I'm attempting to use form_set_value on a webform as well and it's not working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok,

What happens is when going trough the flow, somewhere in one of the functions the variables are not passed as a reference, so you actually loose the information you changed. I fixed this by changing core functionality and passing the object as a reference.

Comment: This is old so you possibly don't remember, but: Are you saying you hacked Drupal core or the webform module to change a variable to be a reference? That could potentially have other side effects. Did you submit it back to the issue queue as a patch for review?

Comment: Better way of changing a value in webform : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728537/how-to-replace-field-value-in-a-drupal-webforms-validator

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer to [form_set_value](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_value/7)() documentation on api.drupal.org.

They say

> if you want to update the value of $form['elem1']['elem2'], which
>   should be stored in $form_state['values']['elem1']['elem2'], you would
>   set $element['#parents'] = array('elem1','elem2').

Hope that helps

Muhammad.

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem is that the way webforms seems to recreate the form after validation is not the same way that forms normally does.

Comment: Ummm, have you checked the weight of your module and webform's weight. Try giving your module a heavier weight than webform's.

As far as I know, webform's weight defaults to (-1)

Comment: I found what is wrong. After the validation hooks are called, the form state is not used to do anything anymore, so values are not altered. Also the $form variable during validation hooks is not defined as a reference variable, so when you adjust values in the $form they are not stored. ...

Comment: Is there a good way to solve this without changing form.inc ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give some more information? Should the value appear with ajax after validating? Also don't forget to `add $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;` at the bottom of your validation function. This will cause the $form array to rebuild based on the values in $form_state. The only thing that form_set_value does is update the $form_state array

Comment: No, I want to add a form element when the validation fails, $form_state['rebuild'] does nothing if error's exist in the form. All I need is indeed to adjust and rebuild the form

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, another approach could be that you form alter your form and do three things: 
1) add to your button(submit?):

> `$form['submit']['#limit_validation_errors'] = array();`

2) override all validation functions with

> `$form['#validate'] = 'own_validation_function_callback'`

3) check if custom valid form_state variable isset

> if (isset($form_state['custom_not_valid'])) {
>   $form['extra_element']
>   = ... }

In your own_validation_function_callback you:
validate your form yourself, maybe with drupal_validate_form()
And if not valid you add to your form_state (if not try to unset it!!)

> `$form_state['custom_not_valid'] = TRUE;`